# Can't install resampy

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, pip, llvmlite

Ubuntu 20.04.2
I am using python2.7 in a virtualenv (because the program I'm trying to build doesn't work with my 3.8)
pip 20.3.4

The program I'm trying to run (involves tensorflow) comes with a file with all the things needed to install (I think that's a dockerfile?).  When I try to run the program I get an error about one of the items in the dockerfile -- resampy.

I get an `ImportError:No module resampy`

I did a `pip install resampy`

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Processing /home/pete/.cache/pip/wheels/19/90/bb/f45e7cc1cfc8f5299c12511fccefcca90c801de995a4e7eb00/resampy-0.2.2-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting numba>=0.32
  Using cached numba-0.47.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (3.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10 in /home/pete/env/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from resampy) (1.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.13 in /home/pete/env/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from resampy) (0.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.3 in /home/pete/env/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from resampy) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch; python_version < "3.4" in /home/pete/env/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from numba>=0.32->resampy) (3.4.0.3)
Collecting llvmlite>=0.31.0dev0
  Using cached llvmlite-0.32.1.tar.gz (104 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/pete/env/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from numba>=0.32->resampy) (44.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: funcsigs; python_version < "3.3" in /home/pete/env/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from numba>=0.32->resampy) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version < "3.4" in /home/pete/env/py2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from numba>=0.32->resampy) (1.1.10)
Building wheels for collected packages: llvmlite
  Building wheel for llvmlite (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/pete/env/py2.7/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-UP2Yh4/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-UP2Yh4/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-ZIPpvD
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-UP2Yh4/llvmlite/
  Complete output (7 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  /home/pete/env/py2.7/bin/python /tmp/pip-install-UP2Yh4/llvmlite/ffi/build.py
    File "/tmp/pip-install-UP2Yh4/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 122
      raise ValueError(msg.format(_ver_check_skip)) from e
                                                       ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  error: command '/home/pete/env/py2.7/bin/python' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for llvmlite
  Running setup.py clean for llvmlite
Failed to build llvmlite
Installing collected packages: llvmlite, numba, resampy
    Running setup.py install for llvmlite ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/pete/env/py2.7/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-UP2Yh4/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-UP2Yh4/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-j9jtLs/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pete/env/py2.7/include/site/python2.7/llvmlite
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-UP2Yh4/llvmlite/
    Complete output (10 lines):
    running install
    running build
    got version from file /tmp/pip-install-UP2Yh4/llvmlite/llvmlite/_version.py {'version': '0.32.1', 'full': 'aa11b129c0b55973067422397821ae6d44fa5e70'}
    running build_ext
    /home/pete/env/py2.7/bin/python /tmp/pip-install-UP2Yh4/llvmlite/ffi/build.py
      File "/tmp/pip-install-UP2Yh4/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 122
        raise ValueError(msg.format(_ver_check_skip)) from e
                                                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    error: command '/home/pete/env/py2.7/bin/python' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/pete/env/py2.7/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-UP2Yh4/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-UP2Yh4/llvmlite/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-j9jtLs/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pete/env/py2.7/include/site/python2.7/llvmlite Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried a `pip3 install resampy` and the result looks better:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: resampy in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (0.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numba>=0.32 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from resampy) (0.52.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.13 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from resampy) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10 in /home/pete/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from resampy) (1.19.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from resampy) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from numba>=0.32->resampy) (45.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: llvmlite<0.36,>=0.35.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from numba>=0.32->resampy) (0.35.0)
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3.3; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

No error.  But when I try and run the program I'm trying to run I still get the original `ImportError`

I admit that I'm in over my head here.  I basically only have a moderate level of python knowledge/experience.  I don't even know what a "wheel" is and I can't find anything in it because "wheel" is kind of hard to google without finding stuff about tires and such.  So even just pointers to learn about what a "wheel" is would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try out this one

```
pip install llvmlite==0.31.0

pip install resampy
```

In my case, the current `llvmlite` package version crashed it. But this package is needed for `resampy`.

You could also try an earlier version of `resampy`, which is independent of `llvmlite`.

```
pip install resampy==0.1.5
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I tried py27 installation failed too before.

But you can install it using py38 via

```
pip install resampy
```

You can test it by

```
pip install -e .[tests]
pip install pytest pytest-cov pytest-faulthandler
py.test --cov-report term-missing --cov resampy
```

The result:
[image]

As for the ImportError, once you successfully installed it, it works well for me:
[image]

Comment: you're right!  It works for me too.  But now I have the problem that the program I want to run uses tensor flow 1.2.1.  And that doesn't work with py385...how would you get around this?  After installing resampy with py385 (in a virtualenv) I tried to go to run the program back in py27 and it's still missing resampy.